# Bounding from below the distance between SDE started from different initial conditions

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W$ be a standard one dimensional Brownian motion, and let $X$ be the solution to the SDE

$$dX_t = \mu(X_t) \, dt + \sigma(X_t) \, dW_t$$

with $\mu, \sigma: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ Lipschitz continuous. We denote by $X^x$ the solution to the SDE starting from $x$ at time $0$.

**Question:** For every $\delta > 0$, does there exist some $\beta > 0$, depending on $\mu$ and $\sigma$ such that for all $x, y \in \mathbb R$ with $|x|, |y| < \delta$, and $t > 0$, we have

$$\mathbb E[|X^x_t - X^y_t|] \geq e^{-\beta t} |x - y|?$$

Comment: Maybe I am missing something but even in the ODE setting that doesn't seem true. For example, consider $x'(t)=-e^{x(t)}$ solved by $x(t)=-\ln(t+e^{-x_{0}})$. Then we have that for large t the difference is $x(t)-y(t)\sim \frac{e^{-x}}{t}(e^{x-y}-1)$. So if we take both large $x,y$ with $x-y=1$ too, we get a contradiction. If you meant small $\delta>0$, then I am not sure for this example but I guess there is a different one by including the $\delta$ in the ODE's definition.

Comment: Order is preserved , you can drop the absolute values, and take expectation, getting fairly simple looking expression

Comment: @ThomasKojar Hm, but the condition is that $|x|, |y| < \delta$, so that they cannot be taken as large as desired.

Comment: @mike That’s a great observation!